# Bootstrap Datepicker end Date is not working with Set Date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

i am using bootstrap datepicker. I am try to set the default Date has the current date in the input field.

```
$(".datepicker-here").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

this above code works but my endDate stops working

```
 $('.datepicker-here').datepicker({
    orientation: "top auto",
    endDate: new Date(),
    templates: {
        leftArrow: '<button icon></button>',
        rightArrow: '<button icon></button>'
    }
});
```

Can you let me known what i am missing?.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    endDate:new Date()
});
$("#datepicker").datepicker('update',new Date('2018-08-12'));
```